# Where to start? How to start?

Tags: community

I'm new to ubuntu.  I want to learn about it, and I want do this as fast as posible.
But I don't know whether to read a book, or try to solve my problems when they arise.  I will appreciate if anyone can help me to do the right thing.

Comment: install Ubuntu. Try is the best way to learn.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My experience is that reading book wont help a lot. You will learn new things but you will forget most of them as you will not be using them. The best way to learn Ubuntu or any other Linux distribution is by practice, so use it as often as you can. Make sure you stick with it i.e keep using it and dont convert back to your old OS when doing something trivial is getting tough. Solve the issues when they arise and use Ubuntu for your everyday tasks i.e watching movies, listening to songs, text/document editing, browsing and etc. After a few days of initial discomfort you will find everything easy.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on your computing experience you may have some knowldege from your previous operating system (presumably Windows). You will find a lot of similarities where many tasks are no problem for you. However some things are done entirely different with Ubuntu. There it is almost impossible to foresee what your individual problems will be. It is this why reading a book will probably fail.

By running Ubuntu you will soon find out that there are few tasks if any that cannot be done. You will learn how to solve your hopefully few problems, and you will find out that solutions may be ridiculously easy once you know the answer.

The best starting point to get solid answers is where you already are: the Community and Ask Ubuntu. We look forward to your questions - just dare to ask.

Answer (score 2):

Learning by doing.Thats the only way.
Reading in forums, askubuntu and other webpages does help a lot.

[Ubuntu-Users (german)](http://ubuntuusers.de/)

[Ubuntu Forum (English)](http://ubuntuforums.org/%20%22Ubuntu%20Forums%20%28English%29)

[Ubuntu Pocket Guide](http://www.ubuntupocketguide.com/index_main.html)

Comment: Yes, like learning to ride a bicycle, you have to get on and pedal.

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3409/beginning-to-learn-unix-and-linux) was posted on the Unix forum.

It may be a bit more advanced than what the average new Ubuntu user wants. I am including it for the other people who are looking for more advanced details.